# Access Wildfly-Docker-Container from Apache-Docker-Container

Tags: java, apache, docker, wildfly

to test my web-application I am building a Docker-Setup.
In one container an apache is running on which the PHP-Frontend is deployed, another container has the wildfly with the actual application running (java .war-file) and a third container has a Postgresql-DB that holds the application's data.

When I am trying now to access the frontend through a browser I receive an exception and it tells me that the wildfly refused the connection.
    fopen(http://172.17.0.3:8080/[...]): failed to open stream: Connection 
refused
I am pretty much out of ideas now and would be rather thankful for every input I can get. I dont really think anyone knows the perfect answer, but maybe I can receive some ideas that get me onto the right track.

So is this due to the wildfly-setup ?
Some authentication problem between the containers ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you on linux or are you using Docker For Mac/Docker for Window/docker machine?

Comment: Debian Linux   Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Debian 4.8.4-1) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) to be precise ;)

Comment: Can we see your command/s?

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: Can you share your docker run command or your docker-compose file?

Comment: docker run -p 9876:9990 -v /root/share:/root/share --name wildfly --entrypoint=/home/container_start.sh -it wildfly_image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docker run -p 9876:9990 -v /root/share:/root/share --name wildfly --entrypoint=/home/container_start.sh -it wildfly_image
```

This command is not exposing the port 8080, you are exposing the port 9876 to 9876

You can try to use localhost:9876

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/

Your service expose an HTTP server on 9990?

Comment: The exposition, as far as I understand, is to expose a port to the "outside", but in my setup the port is not accessed from the outside, but from another docker-container. So i don't think it has to be exposed, since it is also accessed through a "docker-specific" IP-Address. But feel free to correct me

Comment: The problem is you are trying to use a browser to resolve a port that has nothing to expose from your container, because your container communicate with the extern only between the port 9876

Comment: Well if you put it like THAT it sounds kinda obvious, thanks somehow I didnt make that connection, should have been obvious from the IP already.